# $HTTP.DELETE not working local

Tags: angularjs, api

I want to delete a record (package track) with the API from Aftership

This is my code:

```
$scope.delTrack = function($slug, $code){
            $http({
            method: 'DELETE', 
            url: 'https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings/' + $slug + '/' + $code, 
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
                'aftership-api-key': 'APIKEY',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    });
        }
```

This does not work in my webpage, but when I copy the url from the network inspector and insert it in www.hurl.it the delete action works. Probably I'm missing something with the headers or configuration of Angular, but I don't know what...

**Delete url:** https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings/bpost/RS775607677CN

**API Docs:** https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4/trackings/delete-trackings

My GET and POST commands work with the api, the DELETE not.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error, I get a 200 OK, but the record is not deleted and the response is empty... In Hurl the same url call gives a 200 OK with in the response the deleted row